# How to draw image in gray in SWT

Tags: java, swt

I am using following code to draw scaled image in PaintListener.

```
e.gc.drawImage(image,
    0, 0, w, h,
    0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight
);
```

I want to draw image in gray color.

What could be done for that? Does drawImage support some special parameters for that or I should better prepare and convert original image to be grayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to convert it either to greyed-out/disabled using Image class:

```
greyed = new Image(e.display, image, SWT.IMAGE_GRAY);

e.gc.drawImage(greyed,
    0, 0, w, h,
    0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight
);
```

`SWT.IMAGE_DISABLE` also can be used instead of `SWT.IMAGE_GRAY`

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert it to Greyed version before drawing it. GraphicsContext simply draws what you want it to draw.